# When should I free the native (Android NDK) handles?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native-code, resource-leak

I have to use a native library (this is not my decision). The library already has a JNI wrapper, and the example Android NDK code works. But **the library initialization routines return native handles and the developer is required to correctly close them**.

Now, there's an interesting question: **where to call the close_handle routines from?**

At least in theory, each incorrect termination may result in temporary files left somewhere on the disk or some other kind of resource leak.

Library initialization takes from 0.5 to 1 sec and consumes a lot of memory.

An `Activity` is a controller (in MVC sense), Android can kill it because of its own reasons, including turning the device, and the only function that is guaranteed to be called is `onPause()`. So `onPause`/`onResume` is a bad place for a long resource-consuming operation.

(I know about `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`, but I would prefer a solution that does not need it.)

`Application` would be an ideal candidate (I consider the library to be a part of the model), but there is no "application terminates" event.

A `Service` sounds promising, that native library *is* a service, but I just do not see how I can have the desired behavior: the handles must be closed when the application terminates.

Timeouts: sounds like a trade-off, but in fact it guarantees that the memory will not be available the moment it is needed but will become available a few seconds later.

Comment: Exactly what handles are you referring to?

Comment: The details are confidential ("a bit of healthy paranoia is not going to harm anyone"), but the library uses initialization in N steps, each step returning a handle. In C, they are opaque handles; for Java, they get cast to integers. N steps because, at least in theory, you can re-initialize with a bit different parameters.

Comment: The question was down-voted. This is strange unless it means that the support has received a similar inquiry :)

Answer (score 1):

For now, it looks like I indeed need a service, but not exactly `IntentService`: `IntentService` calls `stopSelf()`, while my service should hang around.

It's interesting that `Service.onDestroy()` is called when the user chooses "stop" from "Running services" but not when the user chooses "Force stop" from "Applications". "Stop Debugging" also does not cause `Service.onDestroy()` invocation.

EDIT:

My current solution is to use a class derived from a custom `Service` subclass; the code has been borrowed from the source of `IntentService` found somewhere in the 'net. **In the derived subclass I override `onDestroy()`** and believe that's the best application termination notification available.

```
package com.xyz.customandroid;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;

public abstract class HangAroundIntentService extends Service {
    /** An extra with this name and the value of boolean true marks an intent as a cancel intent. See {@link #markedAsCancelIntent(Intent)}. */
    private static final String CANCEL_MARK = "com.xyz~.customandroid.HangAroundIntentService.cancelQueue()";
    private static final int WHAT_MAGIC = 0; // the "what" field for messages
    private volatile Looper mServiceLooper;
    private volatile ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
    private String mName;
    private boolean mRedelivery;
    private boolean mHangAround = true;

    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        onHandleIntent((Intent)msg.obj);
        if (!mHangAround) {
            stopSelf(msg.arg1);
        }
    }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public HangAroundIntentService(String name) {
    super();
    mName = name;
    }

    /**
     * Remove all pending messages from the handler queue.
     * Processing of the message already fetched from the queue 
     * is not terminated by this function.
     *
     * Although this function is public, it is recommended 
     * to use the cancel intents instead.
     * see {@link #markedAsCancelIntent(Intent)} and {@link #isCancelIntent(Intent)}.
     */
    public void cancelQueue() {
        mServiceHandler.removeMessages(WHAT_MAGIC);
    }

    /**
     * Sets intent redelivery preferences.  Usually called from the constructor
     * with your preferred semantics.
     *
     * <p>If enabled is true,
     * {@link #onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)} will return
     * {@link Service#START_REDELIVER_INTENT}, so if this process dies before
     * {@link #onHandleIntent(Intent)} returns, the process will be restarted
     * and the intent redelivered.  If multiple Intents have been sent, only
     * the most recent one is guaranteed to be redelivered.
     *
     * <p>If enabled is false (the default),
     * {@link #onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)} will return
     * {@link Service#START_NOT_STICKY}, and if the process dies, the Intent
     * dies along with it.
     */
    public void setIntentRedelivery(boolean enabled) {
    mRedelivery = enabled;
    }

    /** 
     * If enabled is true (default), the service does not stop after processing an intent.
     */
    public void setServiceHangAround(boolean enabled) {
    mHangAround = enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    // TODO: It would be nice to have an option to hold a partial wakelock
    // during processing, and to have a static startService(Context, Intent)
    // method that would launch the service & hand off a wakelock.

    super.onCreate();
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("IntentService[" + mName + "]");
    thread.start();

    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    }

    /**
     * If intent is a cancel intent, {@link #cancelQueue()} is invoked immediately;
     * no other action is done for a cancel intent, whatever information it might contain.
     * 
     * Intents that are not cancel intents are queued 
     * to be seen from {@link #onHandleIntent(Intent)}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        if (isCancelIntent(intent)) {
            cancelQueue();
        } else {
        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage(WHAT_MAGIC);
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        msg.obj = intent;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    onStart(intent, startId);
    return mRedelivery ? START_REDELIVER_INTENT : START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    mServiceLooper.quit();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
    }

    /**
     * This method is invoked on the worker thread with a request to process.
     * Only one Intent is processed at a time, but the processing happens on a
     * worker thread that runs independently from other application logic.
     * So, if this code takes a long time, it will hold up other requests to
     * the same IntentService, but it will not hold up anything else.
     *
     * @param intent The value passed to {@link
     *               android.content.Context#startService(Intent)}.
     */
    protected abstract void onHandleIntent(Intent intent);

    /**
     * Mark an Intent as cancel intent. The Intent will not be placed in the queue;
     * instead, it will cause immediate cleaning of the queue
     * (unless you redefine {@link #onStart(Intent, int)} in a derived class).
     * @param intent to be modified
     * @return the original intent after modification
     */
    public static Intent markedAsCancelIntent(Intent intent) {
        intent.putExtra(CANCEL_MARK, true);
        return intent;
    }

    /**
     * Check if the intent has been marked as a cancel intent.
     * @param intent to be checked
     * @return true if it is a cancel intent
     */
    public static boolean isCancelIntent(Intent intent) {
        return intent.getBooleanExtra(CANCEL_MARK, false);
    }
}
```

and my service class is defined as:

```
public class MyService extends HangAroundIntentService {
    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        MyData.getMyData().shutdown();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    // service-specific static methods not shown
}
```

*To be continued...*

Answer (score 0):

In practice, it turned out that some native library leaks resources; I had to do a process restart (this did not kill the activity, but re-created the process):

[how to programmatically "restart" android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609414/howto-programatically-restart-android-app/13173279#13173279)

One can only hope that no library leaks temporary disk files...