# FATAL EXCEPTION: Intent Service while delete SQLite db file from package

Tags: android

I'm deleting Sq-lite database file from android application package on log out button and at that time also want to stop the services which is run in the background but facing error of **FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[helloservice]**.

Here is my Logout button code

```
imgBtn_LogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                stopService(new Intent(Filter_Screen.this, MyService.class));
                stopService(new Intent(Filter_Screen.this,             DownLodProfileSrvice.class));
                Log.e("Service ", " Stop !!!");
                editor.putBoolean("LOG_EVENT", false);
                editor.commit();

                actvitiyContext.deleteDatabase(dbhelper.DATABASE_NAME);
                Log.e("Database", " Deleted Completeley !!!");
                Intent i = new Intent(Filter_Screen.this, Login_Screen.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

Error Log

```
01-04 10:19:06.415  19739-20562/com.example.tazeen.classnkk E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1032) statement aborts at 23: [update ActivityObjectList set DownLoad_Status='1' where imageaudioPath ='560e9df1-a404-47e8-a98b-3d77f0374213.jpg']
01-04 10:19:06.417  19739-20562/com.example.tazeen.classnkk E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[helloservice]
    Process: com.example.tazeen.classnkk, PID: 19739
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:734)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1676)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.MyService.Loaddata(MyService.java:114)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.MyService.onHandleIntent(MyService.java:80)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

This is my service task

```
public void Loaddata() {

            db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from ActivityObjectList", null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do {
                    imageName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imageaudioPath"));
                    str_DownLoadUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DownLoad_Status"));
                    str_ActiveImageStatus = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ActiveStatus"));
                    if(str_ActiveImageStatus.equals("1"))
                    {
                        if( str_DownLoadUrl.equals("0") && imageName.endsWith(mp3_Pattern))
                        {

                            String fileUrl = namespace + "/DownloadFile/FilePathMobile/ATTACHMENT/FileName/"+imageName;
                            newFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "classnkk_audio");
                            download_PngFileImgLoader(fileUrl, newFolder , imageName);
                            db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                            db.execSQL("update ActivityObjectList set DownLoad_Status='1' where imageaudioPath ='" + imageName + "'");

                        }

                        if( str_DownLoadUrl.equals("0") )
                        {
                            if(imageName.endsWith(png_Pattern) || imageName.endsWith(jpg_pattern) || imageName.endsWith(bmp_pattern) || imageName.endsWith(gif_pattern) || imageName.endsWith(jpeg_pattern))
                            {
                                String fileUrl = namespace + "/DownloadFile/FilePathMobile/ATTACHMENT/FileName/"+imageName;
                                newFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "classnkk_images");
                                download_PngFileImgLoader(fileUrl, newFolder, imageName);
                                db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                                db.execSQL("update ActivityObjectList set DownLoad_Status='1' where imageaudioPath ='" + imageName + "'");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
```

Comment: I think you forgot to write `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();` . Before executing any query you must check for this.

Comment: What task u have performed in service ?

Comment: I have performed the task  of retrieve the data and update the data in the task in service.Can i post my service code.

Comment: If possible can u please attach your service code

Comment: I attached service code in above post.

Comment: i think you have to try db.close() when you done your service with database.

Comment: Try to db.close() but getting same issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi can you please try below steps hope it will work for you

You need to close your db after after performing your database related task
 example

```
cursor.close()
 db.close()

public class DeleteDbBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {

        // Stop your service here

            stopService(new Intent(Filter_Screen.this, MyService.class));
            stopService(new Intent(Filter_Screen.this,DownLodProfileSrvice.class));
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {

            // Delete your DB code is here
            context.deleteDatabase("Your DB Path");
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {

                editor.putBoolean("LOG_EVENT", false);
                editor.commit();

                Intent i = new Intent(Filter_Screen.this, Login_Screen.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your expected behavior here ? Do you want to recreate the database when the service restarts or cancel any pending intents that seem to be causing the service to be restarted ?

Comment: When i delete database my services also want to stop with sq-lite performance. Still i face the error of attempt to write a readonly database

Comment: You might have multiple pending intents that restart the service after you called stopService. Maybe look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358190/how-do-i-cancel-all-pending-intents-that-are-qued-for-intent-service ?